# Not able to draw a line between QFrames added in QGridLayout - how to join them by lines?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to build up a Gui in PyQt where I am adding Frames in a Grid layout.
There can be any number of frames present in the layout in each row with a gap of one grid position.
For example: (0,0) (0,2), (1,0), (1,2), (2,0), (2,2) like that.

I want to join each frame with one another by lines and want to show some number as I mouse hover on each line.

However, the lines are not coming up.
I made a simpler application (not using QGridLayout), where lines are coming but it's very difficult to find the positions of the widgets to draw the lines between them from the center of each widget to make it look prominent. Using pos() , it draws from the edge. So I used x() and y() co-ordinate to get the points from the center. Could not find any easy way to depict them.

Below is the simpler application which is somehow working, adding it for demonstration purpose, since I mentioned about it:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel


class Drawer:
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QPen(Qt.green, 2, Qt.SolidLine)));
        #painter.drawLine(self.p1, self.p2)
        painter.drawLine((self.p1x+80), (self.p1y +60), (self.p2x + 80), (self.p2y+ 90) )


class Example(QWidget, Drawer):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        #self.cancelButton.resize(50, 50)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.okButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Buttons")
        self.cancelButton.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 40)

        self.p1, self.p2 = self.okButton.pos(), self.cancelButton.pos()
        print ("p1 ", self.p1 , "| p2 ", self.p2)
        #print (dir(self.okButton))
        self.p1x, self.p1y , self.p2x, self.p2y = int(self.okButton.x()) ,int(self.okButton.y()) , int(self.cancelButton.x()), int(self.cancelButton.y())
        print ("p1x ", self.p1x ,"|p1y ", self.p1y ,"|p2x ", self.p2x, "| p2y ", self.cancelButton.y())
        self.okButton.installEventFilter(self)
        self.cancelButton.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, o, e):
        if e.type() == QEvent.Move:
            if o is self.okButton:
                self.p1 = self.okButton.pos()
            elif o is self.cancelButton:
                self.p2 = self.cancelButton.pos()
            self.update()
        return super().eventFilter(o, e)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the application where I want to connect the QFrames by lines,
the lines should be from the center to center of frames

- How can I make the lines work without the pain of finding the
  co-ordinates?
- mouse hover on line should show some text
  I have added only four frames, but there can be more.

  ```
   import sys
   from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, \
   QAction, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QWidget, QStackedLayout, QGridLayout, 
   QScrollArea, QStyle
   from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen     



   class Drawer:
       def paintEvent(self, event):
           painter = QPainter(self)
           painter.setPen(QPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2, Qt.SolidLine)));
           #painter.drawLine(self.p1, self.p2)
           print ("In paintEvent function = ", self.p1x , " |", self.p1y)
           painter.drawLine((self.p1x), (self.p1y ), (self.p2x + 80), (self.p2y+ 70) )




   class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Drawer):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.setWindowTitle("My App window title")
           self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(176,196,222);")               
           self.centralwidget = QScrollArea()
           self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

           menuBar = self.menuBar()
           fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')        
           openFile = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical), 
               'Open', self)
           fileMenu.addAction(openFile)  

           self.width = 900
           self.height = 500
           self.resize(self.width, self.height)

           self.main_view = QWidget()
           self.main_view.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

           self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()

           self.square1 = QFrame()
           self.square1.setFixedSize(150, 150)
           self.square1.setStyleSheet("background-color:orange")

           self.square2 = QFrame()
           self.square2.setFixedSize(150, 150)
           self.square2.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")



           self.square3 = QFrame()
           self.square3.setFixedSize(150, 150)
           self.square3.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue")


           self.square4 = QFrame()
           self.square4.setFixedSize(150, 150)
           self.square4.setStyleSheet("background-color:cyan")




           btn1 = QPushButton('Orange', self.square1)
           btn2 = QPushButton('green', self.square2)
           btn3 = QPushButton('blue', self.square3)
           btn4 = QPushButton('cyan', self.square4)

           btn1.clicked.connect(self.func1)
           btn2.clicked.connect(self.func2)
           btn3.clicked.connect(self.func3)
           btn4.clicked.connect(self.func4)

           self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.square1,0,0)
           self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.square2,0,2)
           self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.square3,1,0)
           self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.square4,1,2)


           #pos
           self.p1, self.p2 , self.p3 , self.p4 = self.square1.pos(), self.square2.pos(), self.square3.pos, self.square4.pos
           #co-ordinates
           self.p1x, self.p1y  = int(self.square1.x()) ,int(self.square1.y())
           self.p2x, self.p2y  = int(self.square2.x()) ,int(self.square2.y())
           self.p3x, self.p3y  = int(self.square3.x()) ,int(self.square3.y())
           self.p4x, self.p4y  = int(self.square4.x()) ,int(self.square4.y())



           self.main_view.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
           self.centralwidget.setWidget(self.main_view)

       def func1(self):
           print ("This is Orange button")
       def func2(self):
           print ("This is Green button")
       def func3(self):
           print ("This is Blue button")
       def func4(self):
           print ("This is Cyan button")



   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       window = MainWindow()
       window.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec())
  ```

Thanks

Comment: "How can I make the lines work without the pain of finding the co-ordinates?" You can't. You are adding widgets to layout managers, and you are also trying to get their coordinates both **before** the layout has been properly finalized, nor the window completely shown and eventually resized due to layout constraints. Those lines will always be dynamically drawn, so you must always get their geometries and manually compute them. Note that for what you're describing, you may need to consider the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks. An example of how can I use QGraphicsView inside QScrollarea and QGridLayout would have been helpful. And if you can point me to an example of drawing the lines as I require using QGrahicsView will be a good start for me.

Comment: Sorry but the purpose of StackOverflow is not to provide example code or tutorials, and even in the case, that would be off topic for the question, since it uses a completely different implementation. Note that if you use the Graphics View framework, you should not put that into a scroll area, nor a layout: the widget would be *inside* the graphics view. I strongly suggest you to start by studying the introduction linked above and then look for related resources (including questions here on StackOverflow).